# Custom header param - Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, filter, cors

I'm having trouble trying to send a custom header param from my frontend to the controller.

I've set the endpoint to get the header param:

```
public ResponseEntity<DashboardBean> atualizarDadosDashboard(@RequestHeader(name = "idEmpresa") Long idEmpresa){
```

But when I try to consume this endpoint, I get failed response and the application doesn't log any error.

Here I have the browser console showing the failed request:

[image: Browser console error]

The second dashboard request is a OPTIONS type. The first is the GET request.

Here you can see the failed request headers with the custom header "idEmpresa":

[image: request headers]

I'm using Angular on the frontend. As you can see below, I'm adding the header to the request:

```
....

protected httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.token,
        'idEmpresa': String(this.idEmpresa)
    })
};

atualizarDashboard(): Observable<DashboardModel> {
    return this.httpClient.get<DashboardModel>(this.baseUrl, this.httpOptions);
}

....
```

On my spring boot application there is nothing on the logs about this request!!

Comment: check in frontend code if header is passed as strign or number? that could be issue

Comment: thank you @PandeyAmit !! The problem was on my CORS Filter. I have posted the answer below

Comment: As requested, I added more info about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I have a CORS Filter in my application. I had to add my custom header param to the

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers

list to allow it. After that, the endpoint was consumed and worked as expected.

This is how my Filter is now:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("SimpleCORSFilter loaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, " +
                "Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN, idEmpresa");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```